# Why GetInvocationList of System.Delegate class returns array?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am trying to learn how delegates work so I watched over the hierarchy and I found that invocation list of a System.Delegate is actually an array. If all the methods are invoked with the FIFO principle why not store the Delegates in Stack?

In other words why signature of the method `GetInvocationList()`
doesn't look `public virtual Stack<Delegate> GetInvocationList()`
rather than `public virtual Delegate[] GetInvocationList()` or I am missing something?

Comment: Very hard to guess what benefit you see in that.  It doesn't require a resizable collection, an array is also ordered.  A plain jane array is just fine, the framework never adds unnecessary features.

Comment: @HansPassant not saying there is some benefit , just wondering. But I guess Matias answered my question.

Comment: .NET 1.0 also had a Stack class.  There simply is not benefit, that's all.

Comment: If you want a stack make one. Array is more primitive. Not good to pollute core APIs with concerns that don't belong there.

Comment: "If all the methods are invoked with the FIFO principle" -- Huh? When a method is invoked, it doesn't get removed. If a delegate is invoked a second time, all of its methods get invoked a second time. This isn't the FIFO principle at all. FIFO is about taking an item off of the stack/list/whatever, specifically about which item gets taken off, but nothing gets taken off at all here.

Comment: Good note! I guess I misunderstood that part of Invocation list, thanks for giving me heads up!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Delegates are a language feature that was in .NET since its inception.
2. Data structure to store invocation list is just a design decision, but it couldn't be `Stack<T>` because this collection was introduced in .NET 2.0 *(earlier versions had no generic collections or generics at all, they were introduced in .NET 2.0/CLR 2.0)*.

Based on both points, I suspect that it was never changed from `Array` to another data structure because of it would mean that .NET 1.x code would be broken so they decided to maintain backwards compatibility.

BTW, it seems like `Stack<T>` wouldn't be an option because *invocation list* doesn't get released each handler when they're executed.